# JMeter can't read custom search_paths directory

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

I want JMeter to find a jar in lib/ext/custom.

In my jmeter.properties:

```
search_paths=lib/ext/custom
```

When I run the test, I get this output:

```
2019-06-25 10:21:54,792 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: search_paths=lib/ext/custom
2019-06-25 10:21:54,792 WARN o.a.j.JMeter: Can't read lib/ext/custom
```

Does anyone have an idea why it wouldn't be able to read that directory? It has the same owner as all the other directories/files and has the same permissions as lib/ext itself.

I turned the root longer to DEBUG but received no extra information than the above log messages.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. It could not read the directory because it could not find it because the value I provided it wasn't correct.

```
search_paths=../lib/ext/custom
```

It needed that look back to correctly find it. Putting the full path also worked.